# Using bash: how do you find a way to search through all your files in a directory (recursively?)

Tags: bash, shell, search, replace, command

I need a command that will help me accomplish what I am trying to do. At the moment, I am looking for all the ".html" files in a given directory, and seeing which ones contain the string "jacketprice" in any of them.

Is there a way to do this? And also, for the second (but separate) command, I will need a way to replace every instance of "jacketprice" with "coatprice", all in one command or script. If this is feasible feel free to let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec grep -l jacketprice {} \;

for i in `find . -name "*.html"`
do
  sed -i "s/jacketprice/coatprice/g" $i
done
```

Comment: `sed -i` does this in one go.

Comment: Wait could you fix the second line back to the script you had earlier? I was hoping to analyze it anyway for learning purposes! :D

Comment: The for loop will break if find hits any files with spaces or newlines in the name.

Comment: @jordanm - note that the OP asked for this solution to be restored - seems rather crappy that someone votes it down after that request

Answer (score 3):

As for the second question,

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i "s/jacketprice/coatprice/g" {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use recursive grep to search through your files:

```
grep -r --include="*.html" jacketprice /my/dir
```

Alternatively turn on bash's globstar feature (if you haven't already), which allows you to use `**/` to match directories and sub-directories.

```
$ shopt -s globstar 
$ cd /my/dir
$ grep jacketprice **/*.html
$ sed -i 's/jacketprice/coatprice/g' **/*.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want this recursively or not, perl is a good option:

**Find, non-recursive:**

```
perl -nwe 'print "Found $_ in file $ARGV\n" if /jacketprice/' *.html
```

Will print the line where the match is found, followed by the file name. Can get a bit verbose.

**Replace, non-recursive:**

```
perl -pi.bak -we 's/jacketprice/coatprice/g' *.html
```

Will store original with `.bak` extension tacked on.

**Find, recursive:**

```
perl -MFile::Find -nwE '
    BEGIN { find(sub { /\.html$/i && push @ARGV, $File::Find::name }, '/dir'); };
    say $ARGV if /jacketprice/'
```

It will print the file name for each match. Somewhat less verbose might be:

```
perl -MFile::Find -nwE '
    BEGIN { find(sub { /\.html$/i && push @ARGV, $File::Find::name }, '/dir'); };
    $found{$ARGV}++ if /jacketprice/; END { say for keys %found }'
```

**Replace, recursive:**

```
perl -MFile::Find -pi.bak -we '
    BEGIN { find(sub { /\.html$/i && push @ARGV, $File::Find::name }, '/dir'); };
    s/jacketprice/coatprice/g'
```

**Note:** In all recursive versions, `/dir` is the bottom level directory you wish to search. Also, if your perl version is less than 5.10, `say` can be replaced with `print` followed by newline, e.g. `print "$_\n" for keys %found`.